# How to find PID of an ongoing job in UNIX?

Tags: linux, kill, ps, process-management

I executed a shell script which will call some internal applications and will take few hours. Due to some problems, I have to stop or kill that job.
For this, first of all, I ran `ps -u $uname` to list all the ongoing jobs.

```
PID TTY         TIME CMD
 14172 pts/1       0:00 ps
 12939 ?           0:00 sshd
 12904 ?           0:01 sshd
 13132 pts/1       0:00 bash
 12945 pts/1       0:00 sh
 12897 ?           0:00 sshd
```

Now, how will I find correct PID to kill?

Comment: If you add the option `-f` (full) you get more details about the command (CMD). With that information you may be able to do a grep.

Comment: What is the wrong with this question which tends people to downvote?

Answer (score 4):

you can also consider do use

```
pgrep "you_script"
```

or

```
pgrep -f "complete_cmd_line_of_script"
```

"process-grep" results only the PID

If you want to kill the process you found, you also can use pkill, which uses the same syntax as pgrep

Answer (score 2):

```
ps aux | grep "your_script_name.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer would be, since you are interested in the PID only:

```
ps aux | grep yourscript | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: you should pipe grep, grep and awk ! If yourscript is a fixed string 1) use `| grep [y]ourscript` (this avoid a |grep -v grep), 2) then for awk, use `ps aux | awk '/[y]ourscrip/ { print $2} '`

Comment: you mean 'shoud not' if I understand? Thanks for the tip

Comment: yes, **thou shall not**

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | grep "script_name.sh"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ps -aux
```

Is a great command, however, remember that most `cron` jobs are set to reboot if incomplete or have a 'ongoing' daemon.